# Fix "X is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

Tags: sql, group-by

Good morning. I have a query below that requires Total Qty Fulfilled per Item No.

```
select h.cstponbr 'Customer PO No.',
       h.sopnumbe 'Invoice No.', 
       d.itemnmbr 'Item No.',
       d.itemdesc 'Item Description', 
       d.qtyfulfi 'Qty Fulfilled', 
       sum(d.qtyfulfi) 'Total Qty Fulufilled'
from sop10100 h 
inner join sop10200 d on (h.sopnumbe = d.sopnumbe)
where h.cstponbr = @CUSTPONUM
group by d.itemnmbr
```

How will I arrange my query so that I will avoid the error below.

> Column 'sop10100.CSTPONBR' is invalid in the select list because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It means just what it says. Take a peak at the related questions.

Comment: Is it Sql Server?If so, which version?

Answer (score 4):

All columns in the SELECT statement that are not the aggregate functions (in your example, everything except for the sum(d.qtyfulfi) need to be in the GROUP BY clause.

Just list them in the order of grouping hierarchy (in my head I imagine from less to more specific).

Answer (score 4):

```
you can use only columns that are functionally depended on group by clause .
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your query into this,

```
select  h.cstponbr 'Customer PO No.',
        h.sopnumbe 'Invoice No.', 
        d.itemnmbr 'Item No.',
        d.itemdesc 'Item Description', 
        d.qtyfulfi 'Qty Fulfilled', 
        c.totalCount 'Total Qty Fulufilled'
from    sop10100 h 
        inner join sop10200 d 
            on (h.sopnumbe = d.sopnumbe)
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT sopnumbe, SUM(qtyfulfi) totalCount
            FROM sop10200
            GROUP BY sopnumbe
        ) c ON c.sopnumbe = h.sopnumbe
where h.cstponbr = @CUSTPONUM
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Sql Server 2005+, this should work

```
;With Cte As(
Select 
       h.cstponbr 'Customer PO No.',
       h.sopnumbe 'Invoice No.', 
       d.itemnmbr 'Item No.',
       d.itemdesc 'Item Description', 
       d.qtyfulfi 'Qty Fulfilled',
       sum(d.qtyfulfi) Over(Partition By  d.itemnmbr) 'Total Qty Fulufilled',
       Rn =Row_Number() Over(Partition By  d.itemnmbr Order By (Select 1))
from sop10100 h 
inner join sop10200 d on (h.sopnumbe = d.sopnumbe)
where h.cstponbr = @CUSTPONUM  )

Select *
From Cte
Where Rn = 1
```

A more generic should be

```
select h.cstponbr 'Customer PO No.',
       h.sopnumbe 'Invoice No.',
       X.ItemNo,
       X.ItemDescription,
       X.QtyFulfilled,
       X.TotalQtyFulufilled
from sop10100 h 
inner join
            (Select 
                X.ItemNo
                ,d.itemdesc 'ItemDescription'
                ,d.qtyfulfi 'QtyFulfilled'
                ,d.sopnumbe
                ,X.TotalQtyFulufilled
                From sop10200 d
            Inner Join
                (Select d.itemnmbr 'ItemNo',sum(d.qtyfulfi)'TotalQtyFulufilled'
                From sop10200 d
                group by d.itemnmbr)X
            On d.itemnmbr = X.ItemNo)X
on (h.sopnumbe = X.sopnumbe)
where h.cstponbr = @CUSTPONUM
```